# Origen del significado de "trapisonda"

Tags: etimología, significado

Pasando por las mil y una noches, leía como un cadí (especie de juez en el medio oriente) *"(...)vivía de sus [**trapisondas**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aOPQDPj)"*. Después de ir al diccionario a leer el significado del término:

> 2. f. coloq. embrollo (‖ enredo, confusión).

me surge la curiosidad de dónde viene este significado para la palabra.

Es curioso que el DLE no muestre etimología del término. Además hasta finales del Siglo de Oro en el CORDE solo aparece mencionado un par de veces el término (en 1562 y en 1612) y el mapa de diccionarios incluye este significado solo desde finales del siglo XIX, pues antes su único significado era el siguiente:

> s. f. fam. Bulla ó riña con voces ó acciones; y asi se dice: brava TRAPISONDA ha habido. Strepitosa contentio, rixa.

(Del diccionario de 1817 de la academia)

Si bien desde [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?trapisonda) se le asigna a una ciudad y sus posibles significados, no me termina de confirmar el uso de la palabra como sinónimo de *embrollo*. ¿De dónde pudo surgir este significado? o ¿Qué otra fuente confirma el significado?

Comment: Referencia obligada al gran Ibáñez: [_La familia Trapisonda_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_familia_Trapisonda), cómic de 1958.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según Corominas, la palabra significó originalmente 'bulla y riña', registrada en 1739 en el *Autoridades* como bien dices en tu pregunta, y ya hacia el siglo XIX su significado pasó a ser el de 'embrollo, enredo'.

Sobre su origen, dice:

> Del nombre del Imperio de Trapisonda (ciudad de Asia Menor), muy sonado en los libros de Caballerías y el *Quijote*, que gracias al ambiente de esos libros y por su aparente relación con *trápala* y *trapaza*, tomo sus acepciones actuales.

De hecho, el DLE afirma en su edición de 1884 que proviene "de la ciudad de [Trebisonda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebisonda)", aunque en la siguiente edición (1899) ya cambia su origen y plantea de forma dubitativa que puede provenir de [*trápala*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aNfzQcH).

Referencias a la ciudad de Trapisonda hay desde antiguo:

> *É otro dia de mañana, los castellanos que estavan en Constantinopla é los que allí estavan en Pera, me vinieron á ver, é allí conosçí algunos que avía visto en Castilla, entre los quales ví Alfon de Mata, escudero de cavallo del rey Don Juan, nuestro Señor, -que Dios aya,- el qual me rogó mucho que yo lo diese al emperador de Trapisonda, por quél avía venido con los embaxadores del Conçilio, é estaba perdido; [...].*
>
> Pero Tafur, "Andanças e viajes", c 1457 (España).

Y desde luego en el Quijote aparece:

> *—Lo primero en que reparáis de los sonetos, epigramas o elogios que os faltan para el principio, y que sean de personajes graves y de título, se puede remediar en que vos mesmo toméis algún trabajo en hacerlos, y después los podéis bautizar y poner el nombre que quisiéredes, ahijándolos al Preste Juan de las Indias o al Emperador de Trapisonda, de quien yo sé que hay noticia que fueron famosos poetas; [...].*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha", 1605 (España).

La palabra debió calar por su sonoridad, ya que se usó en algunos textos del siglo XVII en tono burlesco:

> *D. Quijote: Corroborante señora,
>
>   ya os sigo.
>
>   Sancho: Ya voy con vos,
>
>   carantamaula amorosa.
>
>   Bernarda: La andante caballería
>
>   os espera en Trapisonda
>
>   para laurear vuestros hechos.
>
>   D. Quijote: No hay para follones gloria. (Vanse Bernarda y don Quijote)*
>
> Juan Vélez de Guevara, "Fin de fiesta para la comedia de Don Quijote de la Mancha [El hidalgo de la Mancha]", 1673 (España).

Y ya en el siglo XVIII:

> *Todo es una niñería,
>
>   Comparado con la broma
>
>   De la que empezó Academia
>
>   Y ha acabado Trapisonda.*
>
> Tomás de Iriarte, "Poesías varias", 1730 - 1791 (España).

Su primer uso como sustantivo común, al menos según los registros del Corde, parece ser este:

> *Amigo y señor: ya que vds. han visto el memorial del P. Cortés no les quedará duda de la trapisonda que ha urdido tal bribon [...].*
>
> José Nicolás de Azara, "Cartas de Azara al ministro Roda en 1768 [Cartas a Don Manuel de Roda]", 1768 (España).

Aunque desde luego sabemos que se usaba desde antes, dado que la voz se registró en el *Autoridades* en 1739.

Así pues, me quedo con lo expresado por Corominas acerca de que la proliferación de la palabra en libros de caballerías y el ambiente creado por estos a partir del *Quijote* (y sus derivados posteriores, como hemos visto) contribuyeron junto con la sonoridad de la palabra y su proximidad fonética a otras como *trápala* a que adquiriera los significados que actualmente se le conocen.

---

Como nota aparte (y como todo un giro de guion en toda regla), buscando en el *Fichero general* de la RAE no aparece nada si buscas el término *trapisonda*, pero sí que salen resultados si buscas *trapisondo* (?). En una de las fichas encontradas se afirma:

> **Trapisonda.** [...] En los libros de caballerías se menciona mucho [el nombre de la ciudad], y á Cervantes debió de caerle en gracia por lo sonoro del nombre y por despertar la idea de *trapisonda* y *trapisondista*.

¿Es posible que el significado de *trapisonda* como 'bulla' ya existiera desde antes del *Quijote*?